# Why do we "require" ngModel in a directive vs inject it?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Why do we "require" ngModel in a directive instead of in the directive injection arguments?

```
 angular.module('customControl', ['ngSanitize']).
      directive('contenteditable', ['$sce', function($sce) {
        return {
          restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
          require: '?ngModel',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directives aren't injected. They are placed on elements which means that you need a specific instance in your custom directive.

`require`ing another directive on your own custom directive is how you tell Angular that to use your directive on an element, another directive is needed for things to work properly.

Comment: so is ngModel a directive that provides some special controllers and functionality?

Comment: I'm confused cause my directive has: require: 'ngModel', but doesn't use ngModel anywhere in the link function

Comment: but it is used in the use case: <input type="text" ng-model="foo"